# Oldest monasteries where natural science is still practiced?

Tags: catholicism, science, clergy

Science and religion are actually not mutually exclusive at all.
In history, we know many examples of [clerical scientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Catholic_cleric-scientists).

What is the oldest still existing convent (monastery) where monks still pursue research in the natural sciences?

Comment: Science is not done in convents. Those scientists who are members of religious orders do so in scientific institutions. Although you should also know about the [Vatican Observatory](http://www.vaticanobservatory.va/content/specolavaticana/en.html)

Comment: @DJClayworth: The monasteries which involved themselves most deeply in science eventually became the Universities, like the Pontifical Gregorian, _La Sapienza_, or Oxford. Catholic-majority countries have also plenty of so-called Pontifical Universities which are tended at least partially by clerics and are subject to the local bishop.

Comment: Actually, consider [this monastery](https://www.stift-klosterneuburg.at/en/monastery-and-order/vocations/science/)...

Comment: @DJClayworth Isn't the asker asking specifically about science done in monasteries? The Jesuits are not monastic.